# Python error "function not defined"

Tags: python, shuffle

```
def shuffledCards():

    CardList = ["AC","AD","AH","AS",
                "KC","KD","KH","KS",
                "JC","JK","JH","JS",
                "QC","QK","QH","QS",
                "2 C", "2 D", "2 H", "2 S",
                "3 C", "3 D", "3 H", "3 S",
                "4 C", "4 D", "4 H", "4 S",
                "5 C", "5 D", "5 H", "5 S",
                "6 C", "6 D", "6 H", "6 S",
                "7 C", "7 D", "7 H", "7 S",
                "8 C", "8 D", "8 H", "8 S",
                "9 C", "9 D", "9 H", "9 S",]

    cardAmount = len(CardList)
    shuffledDeck = []
    for I in range(0,cardAmount):
        randIndex = randint(0,cardAmount - I - 1)
        shuffledDeck.append(CardList[randIndex])
        del CardList [randIndex]
    return shuffledDeck



## At this point we need to draw cards

def drawCard(shuffledDeck):

    if shuffledDeck <= 0:
        shuffledCards()
    else:
        card = shuffledDeck[0]
        del shuffledDeck[0]
    return card     



def main():
    shuffledCards()
    print(shuffledCards())
    drawCard(shuffledDeck)
    print(shuffledCards())
    print (card)


main()
```

When I run the program it prints out the shuffledCards but then it gives me an error with `drawCard(shuffledDeck)` saying shuffledDeck is not defined.

This is the output:

> ['8 D', '4 D', 'AS', '8 H', '4 H', '2 S', 'QC', 'QS', '3 D', 'AC', '9 S', 'JS', 'QK', '2 C', '9 H', '5 H', 'JC', '2 D', '6 C', 'KS', '9 D', '9 C', '5 C', 'AH', '2 H', 'AD', '7 D', 'KC', '6 D', 'KD', '3 S', '5 S', '7 H', 'JH', '7 S', '6 H', '7 C', 'JK', '8 S', '6 S', '3 H', '4 S', '4 C', 'QH', '5 D', 'KH', '3 C', '8 C']
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "E:\University of Utah\Fall 2015\EAE 1410\Homework\Assignment 5\HW05_Blackjack.py", line 71, in 
>           main()
>         File "E:\University of Utah\Fall 2015\EAE 1410\Homework\Assignment 5\HW05_Blackjack.py", line 66, in main
>           drawCard(shuffledDeck)
>       NameError: name 'shuffledDeck' is not defined

Comment: `shuffledDeck` is a local variable in `shuffledCards`, it is not available outside `main`. Probably you need `shuffledDeck = shuffledCards()` in `main`

Comment: And same applies to `card`

Comment: Thanks, this answered my quetion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables declared inside functions are local to that function, (if you thought it would be available as a global).  You return the deck, but don't save it.  I think the first line of "def main():" should have been:

```
shuffledDeck = shuffledCards()
```

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question.